# How to remove Required Attribute From Django Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to remove required attribute from HTML Form. And it should give error from server side that this field is required. Previously i was using required `self.fields['group_name'].required=False`. But it is not giving error for blank or null data. Then i came to know `use_required_attribute`, but i don't know about it and how to use it.

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    use_required_attribute = False
    class Meta:
        model = Groups
        fields = ['group_name', 'group_description', 'group_status']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not giving error for blank or null data"? You can set up your own `clean_group_name` method in form definition. Regarding the required attribute, you can set it in the format definition as said in the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `form = GroupForm(use_required_attribute=False)` when you initialize your form in your `views.py`.